# Cross Platform Encryption and Decryption

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

Is there any cross platform AES 256 Encryption and decryption that supports both iOS(Swift) and C# application. Apart from
https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption.

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt all my data.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same class(https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption) for AES encryption/decryption in C#,IOS and Android.It works fine with C# and android but not working with IOS.Finally found the below solution which working fine in IOS.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        NSString *sData = @"Meet me at the secret location at 8pm";
        NSString *sIv = @"4QesEr03HwE5H1C+ICw7SA==";
        NSString *sKey = @"ovA6siPkyM5Lb9oNcnxLz676K6JK6FrJKk4efEUWBzg=";

        NSData *dData = [sData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dEncrypt = [self doCipher:dData key:sKey iv:sIv context:kCCEncrypt];
        NSData *base64 = [dEncrypt base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
        NSString *sBase64 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:base64 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Base64 String: %@",sBase64);

        NSData *dDecrypt= [self decrypt:dEncrypt key:sKey iv:sIv];
        NSString *sDecrypt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dDecrypt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Decrypted Data: %@",sDecrypt);
    }

    - (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText
                     key:(NSString *)key
                      iv:(NSString *)iv
                 context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
    {
        NSUInteger dataLength = [plainText length];

        size_t buffSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
        void *buff = malloc(buffSize);

        size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

        NSData *dIv = [iv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *dKey = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                                         kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                         kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                         dKey.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                         dIv.bytes,
                                         [plainText bytes], [plainText length],
                                         buff, buffSize,
                                         &numBytesEncrypted);
        if (status == kCCSuccess) {
            return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buff length:numBytesEncrypted];
        }

        free(buff);
        return nil;
    }
```

For more details check this thread.
[Decrypt a base64 string using C# generated by iOs CCCrypt function using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242317/decrypt-a-base64-string-using-c-sharp-generated-by-ios-cccrypt-function-using-ae)

Answer (score 0):

In one of project there's requirement for Cross platform(C#,Android,IOS) AES encryption/decryption.
I have tried https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption but it creates issue with IOS.
So I have implemented AES which works fine with C#,IOS and Android.

**C#**

```
    public class AESCrypto
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Encrpyts the sourceString, returns this result as an Aes encrpyted, BASE64 encoded string
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="plainSourceStringToEncrypt">a plain, Framework string (ASCII, null terminated)</param>
            /// <param name="passPhrase">The pass phrase.</param>
            /// <returns>
            /// returns an Aes encrypted, BASE64 encoded string
            /// </returns>
            public static string EncryptString(string plainSourceStringToEncrypt, string passPhrase)
            {
                //Set up the encryption objects
                using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acsp = GetProvider(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(passPhrase)))
                {
                    byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainSourceStringToEncrypt);
                    ICryptoTransform ictE = acsp.CreateEncryptor();

                    //Set up stream to contain the encryption
                    MemoryStream msS = new MemoryStream();

                    //Perform the encrpytion, storing output into the stream
                    CryptoStream csS = new CryptoStream(msS, ictE, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    csS.Write(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length);
                    csS.FlushFinalBlock();

                    //sourceBytes are now encrypted as an array of secure bytes
                    byte[] encryptedBytes = msS.ToArray(); //.ToArray() is important, don't mess with the buffer

                    //return the encrypted bytes as a BASE64 encoded string
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Decrypts a BASE64 encoded string of encrypted data, returns a plain string
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="base64StringToDecrypt">an Aes encrypted AND base64 encoded string</param>
            /// <param name="passphrase">The passphrase.</param>
            /// <returns>returns a plain string</returns>
            public static string DecryptString(string base64StringToDecrypt, string passphrase)
            {
                //Set up the encryption objects
                using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acsp = GetProvider(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(passphrase)))
                {
                    byte[] RawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64StringToDecrypt);
                    ICryptoTransform ictD = acsp.CreateDecryptor();

                    //RawBytes now contains original byte array, still in Encrypted state

                    //Decrypt into stream
                    MemoryStream msD = new MemoryStream(RawBytes, 0, RawBytes.Length);
                    CryptoStream csD = new CryptoStream(msD, ictD, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    //csD now contains original byte array, fully decrypted

                    //return the content of msD as a regular string
                    return (new StreamReader(csD)).ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            private static AesCryptoServiceProvider GetProvider(byte[] key)
            {
                AesCryptoServiceProvider result = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                result.BlockSize = 128;
                result.KeySize = 128;
                result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                result.GenerateIV();
                result.IV = new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

                byte[] RealKey = GetKey(key, result);
                result.Key = RealKey;
               // result.IV = RealKey;
                return result;
            }

            private static byte[] GetKey(byte[] suggestedKey, SymmetricAlgorithm p)
            {
                byte[] kRaw = suggestedKey;
                List<byte> kList = new List<byte>();

                for (int i = 0; i < p.LegalKeySizes[0].MinSize; i += 8)
                {
                    kList.Add(kRaw[(i / 8) % kRaw.Length]);
                }
                byte[] k = kList.ToArray();
                return k;
            }   
        }

**JAVA -Andorid**

public class AESHelper {

    /*This method use to encript the sting  */
    public static String encrypt(String inputString) throws Exception {
        byte[] result = encrypt(inputString.getBytes());
        String result1 = Base64.encodeToString(result,
                Base64.NO_WRAP);//Instead of Default
        return result1;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        byte[] result = decrypt(data);
        String original = new String(result, "UTF-8");

        return new String(original);
    }

    /*This method return encrypted text with byte code*/
    private static byte[] encrypt( byte[] message) throws Exception {
        byte[] KEY = ConstantData.key.getBytes();//Key for encryption

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        byte[] ivx =  new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};//make same as web team
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivx);
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);

        byte[] encrypted = ecipher.doFinal(message);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] KEY = ConstantData.key.getBytes();//Key for decrypt

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        byte[] ivx =  new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};//make same as web team
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivx);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,ivSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
```

For **IOS** there are few files so not able to put the code here.You can find the source code from below url.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05dZSkNGcb-RXkxcjBNd21TNXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)